Call UI doesn't appear on incoming and outgoing calls on Huawei
I have a Huawei P20 Lite, running EMUI 9.0, whose default dialer app became unusable. When making a call, the in-call screen doesn't show up and the only way to hang up is with the power button. When receiving a call, nothing shows up except the dropdown menu banner.
I reverted the system version to 8.0, and it was working normally until recently.
I ran logcat while making and receiving calls and found a recurring error:
05-09 10:12:57.371  2208  9003 E AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: androidmapsapi-Background_2
05-09 10:12:57.371  2208  9003 E AndroidRuntime: Process: com.android.incallui, PID: 2208
05-09 10:12:57.371  2208  9003 E AndroidRuntime: m.bgr: Exception while extracting native library.
05-09 10:12:57.371  2208  9003 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.google.android.apps.gmm.jni.util.NativeHelper.safeLoadLibrary(:com.google.android.gms.policy_maps_core_dynamite@241110202@241110201008.615149234.615149234:207)
05-09 10:12:57.371  2208  9003 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.google.android.apps.gmm.jni.util.NativeHelper.ensureLibraryLoaded(:com.google.android.gms.policy_maps_core_dynamite@241110202@241110201008.615149234.615149234:78)
05-09 10:12:57.371  2208  9003 E AndroidRuntime:    at m.dmi.run(:com.google.android.gms.policy_maps_core_dynamite@241110202@241110201008.615149234.615149234:1)
05-09 10:12:57.371  2208  9003 E AndroidRuntime:    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:457)
05-09 10:12:57.371  2208  9003 E AndroidRuntime:    at m.cct.run(:com.google.android.gms.policy_maps_core_dynamite@241110202@241110201008.615149234.615149234:12)
05-09 10:12:57.371  2208  9003 E AndroidRuntime:    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
05-09 10:12:57.371  2208  9003 E AndroidRuntime:    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
05-09 10:12:57.371  2208  9003 E AndroidRuntime:    at m.cdj.run(:com.google.android.gms.policy_maps_core_dynamite@241110202@241110201008.615149234.615149234:44)
05-09 10:12:57.371  2208  9003 E AndroidRuntime:    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:784)
05-09 10:12:57.371  2208  9003 E AndroidRuntime: Caused by: m.bgr: Zip entry 'lib/arm64-v8a/libgmm-jni.so' not found in APK '/system/priv-app/InCallUI/InCallUI.apk'
05-09 10:12:57.371  2208  9003 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.google.android.apps.gmm.jni.util.NativeHelper.safeLoadLibrary(:com.google.android.gms.policy_maps_core_dynamite@241110202@241110201008.615149234.615149234:174)
05-09 10:12:57.371  2208  9003 E AndroidRuntime:    ... 8 more

How should this exception be mitigated?

Welcome, we have an existing Q&A about the same recent issue of Huawei's Phone app.  Looking at the logcat, seems it's related to Google Maps and/or Google Play Services, which one of the answers mentioned. Please take a look.
